# Python equivalent of Matrix::chol and Matrix::solve in R?

Tags: python, r, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

In R I am doing the following:

```
L = ... # some sparse matrix L
chol_factor = Matrix::chol(L)

b = # some vector
z = Matrix::solve(chol_factor, b)
```

where `solve` will be smart about efficiently calculating things via the Cholesky factor. I have been using `scipy.sparse` for most of my code, but there doesn't seem to be a Cholesky decomposition implementation available, nor a way to efficiently solve using the factor. Is there an equivalent way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via scipy's sparse LU decomposition.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import linalg as sla

L = # some sparse matrix 
lu = sla.splu(L)

b = # some vector
z = lu.solve(b)
```